# Where do Recently Published Applications can be found?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm about to upload a new Application and I want to know where do this application will appear to the users, or, if it will appear at all somewhere.

I know that there is a "Top New Free Apps" but isn't there something like just "New Apps"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old version of the Market there used to be a "Just In" category. That has since been wiped with the new version. It has been replaced with "Top New Apps". That is the closest equivalent to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That really sucks, since advertising is expensive and, though a valid option, it won't guarantee that our app will be able to over-pay it's costs.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have seen, but the Android Market were to do that, it would be constantly changing list where applications would only be visible for short while, since new stuff is added quite often.

What you could do is generate a QR code that contains the android market link and post on your web site or where ever else you want.

[ZXING QR code generater](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/).

Comment: I know that, but yet, It would be useful to be on that list for just two seconds. Might make wonders with a good App-Description